# What is a word that describes a person who has difficulty speaking with girls?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word or phrase that describes "a person who is having difficulty speaking with girls?"

Comment: Is it specifically *girls* or is it *the opposite sex* (a girl who has difficulty speaking with boys)?  Is the difficulty related to a specific mode, like flirting?

Comment: computer programmer ;)

Comment: @gbutters I resemble that remark!

Comment: Until I got married, "Jeff" would have been a good fit.

Comment: For girls who have difficulty speaking to boys "wallflower" would do the job.

Comment: @Christi - I actually hear that word applied to guys too. I think it refers to people who spend the entire time at a (early to mid 20th century-style) dance "planted" at one of the far walls. Arguably, a girl is less likely to have this apply to them for being shy, as their emotional bravery isn't really what gets them asked to dance or not. Not being a girl, I can't claim expertise on that though. Just my outside perspective.

Comment: A *guy*, perhaps?

Comment: "Single" is the likely answer.

Answer (score 17):

"Shy" would be a description of someone who has difficulty speaking with people.  You could describe someone as "Shy around girls", but knowing more about why they were shy might lead us to a better phrase.

Comment: *Bashful* is close to *shy* as well.

Comment: Excellent point, and much more associated with being shy around girls too.

Comment: Also, an oddly popular name among [dwarves](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Bashful).

Comment: Great. I created an account here just so I could upvote this.

Answer (score 10):

I've seen in various old books (*Vanity Fair*, if I rightly recall) such a person described as a [hobbledehoy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hobbledehoy), meaning an awkward, tongue-tied young man.

Comment: Neat word, and seems terribly obscure.

Answer (score 9):

**parthenophobe**

> In psychology, [Parthenophobia](http://psychology.wikia.com/wiki/Parthenophobia) refers
>   to an abnormal and persistent fear of
>   virgins or young girls.

<sup>*Psychology Wiki*</sup>

Comment: Is that derived from Parthenon - a place where virgins are found?

Comment: +1 Not exactly common usage, but I love that there's a word that mean "fear of virgins." It's going on my bulletin board right now.

Comment: Heh. I don't think that's quite what he was going for, but I love the word.

Comment: @pavium: the Parthenon is the temple of Athene Parthene, Athena the Virgin. So yes, in a way.

Comment: Except that doesn't seem to be a real condition, just a coined word. It's a neat word, and it means what it sounds like, but it's well, made up and not in common use. Wikis aren't always the best source for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who has difficulty speaking in stressful situations (such as the computer programmer and the girl) may be described as "tongue-tied".

Comment: Upvote for subtle Red Dwarf reference.

Answer (score 1):

A **geek** or a **computer geek** could work for this kind of person.

Answer (score 0):

How about "selective mutist", a selective mutist is someone who cannot talk in certain conditions, but is quite chatty in others. For instance, a boy at school having difficulty chatting with other girls, but when he gets home, jokes around a lot with his sister.

EDIT:

If that wasn't clear enough, how about "parthenophobic selective mutist"....

Comment: I don't think *mutist* is a word.  I think you want *mute* here.

Comment: @Kit, not really sure myself, but it is taken from selective mutism. So someone who has selective mutism could be selective mutist, who is selectively mute in certain situations...

Comment: @Kit, I was doubtful about the term, but I saw a television program only a few days ago which described 'selective mutism' in various people. They didn't use the term *selective mute*, preferring the slightly more euphemistic *selective mutist*.

Comment: Upvote for subtle Big Bang Theory reference.

Answer (score 0):

"Painfully bashful" implies the person has a hard time talking or interacting with other people. "He was painfully bashful when in the presence of girls."

Answer (score -2):

I would say [Coy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coy) is related especially to Bashful/Shy - by not necessarily when talking to girls

Comment: "Coy" is more like not speaking for strategic purposes, rather than not being emotionally able to speak.

Answer (score -4):

> Misogynist

This would be someone who chooses not to speak to women.  Not out of fear or shyness but out of dislike.  It has more of a negative connotation though.

Comment: I think [misogynist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/misogynist) is really extreme for this context, considering it implies hatred and mistrust of women and carries a very negative connotation.  And though a misogynist might choose not to speak to a woman, I don't think that's a typical trait associated with misogynists.

Comment: @Kit - My answer was based of a real life scenario.  A professor where I went to school refused to speak to any female coworkers after he was accused of sexual harassment.